# Array insertion in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, shift, operation

I have 2 float arrays. There's a K variable read from the keyboard. I have to insert into the 1st array the elements of the 2nd array after the value of K. Example:

array 1 (7 elements): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
array 2 (3 elements): 9, 10, 11

Let's say K=4

array 1 becomes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7 (So K elements at a time from each array)

How would I move the elements to the right (in array 1) to insert the elements of array 2 (and repeat the process)? I'd prefer to avoid using any C++ 11 array functions (transform, sort etc.)

Comment: sounds like homework. are you allowed to create a new array to return as the result? (you'd better post the initial code you've written if you seek help)

Comment: are you allowed to use `std::vector`s or simple C-arrays?

Comment: `std::sort` and `std::transform` and many other algorithms were in C++98, so have at. Lots will work work on C arrays too. Perhaps you mean to say that you have to/want to reinvent the wheel for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like homework, I only give you some hints about the solution, no full code.

Devide the task into two sub-tasks: Moving elements in the first array to the right by some offset (the number of elements to be inserted, i.e. the length of the second list), and moving elements from the second array to the first array where you just moved away the elements. *Do not* repeat this procedure for each element you insert, but rather move the elements by the (already known) size of the second array. This should be faster than what you described.

To avoid the need for a temporary copy (so it can be "in place", and in your comments you said you aren't allowed to allocate a third (temporary) array), you have to start moving elements from the end. This ensures that you don't overwrite values you later need, which would be the case if you started to move the elements from the left.

Let's say the part to be moved in the first array starts at some index `start` (in your question this is `K` I guess) and the whole array has length `end` (i.e. `end` is the index of the element "one past the end").

Write a loop which iterates through the *source* indices (i.e. where you *read* the old values) in your first array. Move them by the offset in your first array. Note that this loop, as explained above, iterates *backwards*, i.e. you need something like `for (int index = end-1; index >= start; --index)`. This loop starts at the last element (`end-1`; note that `end` is the length and thus points *after* the array) and ends (inclusively) at `start`.

After moving the elements to the right, you can start moving elements from the second array to the first. Here the order doesn't matter, so I would prefer iterating forward for simplicity.

As discussed below this answer, I assume that enough space is already allocated in array 1. Please make sure that this is the case in your code. Since you're not allowed to allocate a third array, there is no other option than this. (Unless you are allowed to use automatic allocation in the form of dynamic-sized data structures like `std::vector`)

Comment: Another problem occuring if not allowed to use a temporary array is the size. In his example array 1 becomes larger. Without a new array one will have to allocate more space after array 1. If this is really homework the task sounds more like he is supposed to use vectors.

Comment: I assume that enough space is already allocated. If not, this is another task which can be implemented separately.

Comment: lol you HAVE to think about it before start thinking about the rest

Comment: `there is no other option than this` this is not quite right, one could use `malloc`, bascially the same `std::vector` does

Comment: @Paranaix I assumed this is what the teacher meant with "no third array".

Comment: No i meant it differently. I mean to allocate more space AFTER the array, not to allocate a completely new array.

Comment: This would be some new magic stuff if you could tell malloc *where* to allocate the space. You could argue about using `realloc` though. But still, I'd better not use `malloc` but rather `new[]` in which case there is no `renew[]` ;)

Comment: Well sorry, im not that quite much into the c stuff but `realloc` should do the job

Comment: Your "move to the right" part only moves the elements by *one* position, but you need space for `n2` elements. In particular `a[i+1]` is wrong. Do you know what to write instead? A second mistake is that you only copy over `K` elements, but `K` is not the size of your second array.

Answer (score -1):

My answer may not exactly answer your question. But as you are using c++ not c, you should use vectors not arrays.

```
vector<int> vec1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
vector<int> vec2{9, 10, 11};
vec1.insert(vec1.begin()+k,vec2.begin(),vec2.end());
```

This is just enough for all your need;

Comment: The OP explicitely states he HAS to use arrays

Comment: Poor OP is not allowed to use it, so this is not a valid answer (though it is "better").

Comment: @leemes should I delete my answer. I thought it'd be a better choice.